# Jquery Warning If Search Bar is Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a simple code of my search bar and jquery. I want to add a alert if Search Bar Filter is empty and we press on button.

```
<form id="searchbar"class="form-inline">
   <input style="width:450px"class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
   <button id="arama"class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        if ($('input').val().length === 0) {
            $('input').parents('p').addClass('warning');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Change `<button type=submit` to `<button type=button` then it won't submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the form from submitting when you want to display the warning, you can `return false` inside your if statement:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      if( $('input').val().length === 0 ) {
        $('input').parents('p').addClass('warning');
        return false; // Add this line
      }
    });
  });
```

Also, in your snippet you don't have a `<p>` tag to which you can add the `warning` class, so with your exact snipped you won't actually add the class to anything.

Comment: So firstyle I should create a class warning and then make it display:none?

Comment: I was just basing my answer on your code - I don't know if you have a parent `<p>` tag or `warning` class. I don't understand what you wish to accomplish by making the tag `display:none`, which hides the element. Could you elaborate?